# Sitecore JSS Personalization simple display rule not working

Tags: jss, experience-editor, personalization

We are using Sitecore 9.1 with JSS and have a fully functional site running using Angular -- all working great.  Now, we would like to add personalization to our site.  To do so as a simple starting point, I navigate to our application and insert a new page to our "home" root.  I add a simple Left Navigation component to the page and then go to Personalize the display.  I add a rule to "Show" the component when the day of the week is Monday and default to "Hide" the component otherwise like so:   [image]

As soon as I get back to the Experience Editor and choose the "Change condition" dropdown and pick the "Check Day of week" condition, the component does not hide.  (it is not Monday)  Odd thing is, sometimes this works for me but when I save the component, it reverts to no longer working.  (not hiding the component when I choose the day condition)
[image]

Any ideas why I cannot get personalization to "stick"?

Comment: in this context, it is not supposed to evaluate personalization rules. It is intended for preview of the rendering. You should rather use Preview mode of the Experience Editor

Comment: Thanks for the response lebeg.  I have always been able to "spot check" personalized rules by clicking the numbered "Available Conditions:" in the window displayed above and seeing the UI change behind it.  We also run a non-JSS based site (traditional MVC) on this same server and I can add this simple rule and see the expected show/hide behavior behind it.   Are you saying this is not possible with JSS and Preview must be used?  I will try it but I'm not sure I understand why it would be different.  Thanks!